# How to update a form field in MS Access once condition has been met

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-forms

I need to update the Completion Metric field once a SubjectID is specified. Here is a sample of the data :
[image]

There is a form that is connected to this table and I need the Completion Metric field in the form to show once the SubjectID on the form is specified. So far I have set the control source to the Completion_metric field from the table that is linked to the form. However, I am unsure whether the Access will automatically update the Completion Metric field once the other fields have been filled in or I have to use VBA. (below are 2 pictures of the form)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Must use code (macro or VBA). Where does completion metric value come from?

Comment: @June7  completion metric value comes from a table

Comment: I think I must code in the AfterUpdate event because the value of the completion metric can only be displayed when form is filled out. So access can locate which record do use to display the completion metric

Comment: Then attempt some code. Use DLookup(). When you have specific issue, post question with sample data (as text tables, not images) and code. This is a very common topic. How is Completion Metric related to SubjectID?

Comment: Subject Id is what is used for identification so each subject id has its own completion metric. So what I am trying to do is display the value of the completion metric once the subject id is specified. Do I use the AfterUpdate event for the subject id text box to display the value of the completion metric for that subject id?

Comment: That doesn't explain how the data is related. Edit question to show sample data as text tables or post to a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis. The AfterUpdate event would seem to be correct but since I don't know your db, can't say for sure. I am not even sure you should save this value into this table if it can be retrieved by joining related tables.