# Which form event to use to update a form once form has loaded

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

A text box on my MS Access form needs to display a value once someone enters information onto the other fields in the form. The text box has a control source from a table so once someone enters information into the other fields, the set box should display the from the table it is linked to. So essentially, I entering the information into the other fields locates the record and field that my textbook should display.
Should I add an event procedure to the Form_Load event? or do I add an event procedure to the txtbpx_AfterUpdate event in order to display the value of the textbook?

I am new to using MS access forms so please answer while keeping in mind that I am a new user of MS Access form.

Comment: _Form_Load_ only runs when the form loads, so use the _AfterUpdate_ event of the textbox being updated.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68259025/how-to-update-a-form-field-in-ms-access-once-condition-has-been-met